# Not able to install boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have python 2.7 version installed.When i check for pip version it says below

```
     pip --version
     9.3
```

When i try to update pip using below command

```
     python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It says `pypi.python.org timed out.....Requirement already up to date`

Now i want to install boto3 for that i am using below command

```
    pip install boto3
```

But it says

```
    "retry connection timeout ....
    "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from 
     versions: )"
```

Any idea why i am not able to install boto3?.Infact i am not able to install any other package like bs4 etc

Comment: You are trying to install it for Python2.7? Or 3.x Or is it a situation where it doesn't matter? The tags are confusing.
What machine is it running on? 
Can you print the full error?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: @Uberhumus I have to install boto in Python 2.7 only and i am running these commands on windows command prompt.

Comment: @Ninad yes i am behind corporate firewall.

Comment: @AWS_Lernar It is likely that your access to https://pypi.org/ is blocked since you are getting connection timeout. Ask your network admin to grant you access.

Comment: Hi All,Looks like it was a access issue.I got some proxy setting commands from one of colleague and it worked.